# Are there rules to play as a True Drake in Shadowrun 5e?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

As far as I've seen there are no rules for True Drakes in Shadowrun 5th Edition. [The rules for Drakes are detailed in *Howling Shadows*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62327/is-there-a-known-reason-for-drakes-not-being-in-the-5th-edition-compendium), and True Drakes appeared in previous editions. I would like to know if there are rules for them somewhere for 5th edition or plans to release them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Sorry, no

At present, there are no rules in place for True Drakes in 5th Edition. All reference in the books to Drakes speaks as if the "I'm a metahuman who spontaneously turns into a dracoform" is the only template that exists. In fact, there are no references to True Drakes at all, even in the Fiction sections.

Comment: By the way, *true drakes* are one of those things shared between shadowrun and earthdawn settings (as horrors, named dragons and the harlequin), and as they are owned by different companies now, its possible we will see less about them.

Comment: Does this mean that all fiction published prior to the current owner is retconned? Ie Ryan Mercury

Comment: @MatthewP Catalyst has never specified, but as far as I am aware...they don't retcon fiction if they can help it. They might _ignore_ something when it comes to making rules or telling stories in a new edition, but 'prior fiction' is not _automatically_ retconned...and I have not heard anything recent from Catalyst about specific retcons.